# Convert a Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Attachment to a Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Herocard

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a method wherein I have passed a HeroCard as an attachment.
Now, I want to use the same attachment in order to get the HeroCard back.

Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `Content` of the `Attachment` will contain the card as you can see in the [CreateAttachment](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/3a98a6b3d15962a57b5454bfb3f730d3588de3ef/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Shared/CardEx.cs#L82-L89) method that is being called by the `ToAttachment` extension method from the cards.